# Nexmo balance check with message alert box

Tags: javascript, php, html, alert, vonage

I want to show my Nexmo balance in an alert message box button. Will you please guide me that How can I do this?

```
<head>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      alert("Your Total Balance is : " . $balance . " Euro  ");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Check Balance" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your PHP variable is `$balance`, use the below script. You have to transfer the string from the PHP variable to a JavaScript variable.

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var balance = '<?php echo $balance; ?>';
alert("Your Total Balance is : " + balance + " Euro");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Check Balance" />
```

Comment: This is showin undefined Euros....

here is my php script.

    include ( "account.php" );
    if(isset($_POST['to'])){
    $pass = $_POST['password1'];
    $key = 'ccc5545fd';
    $password = 'de4256f';
    $nexmo_balance = new NexmoAccount($key, $secret);
    $balance = $nexmo_balance->balance();

Comment: ^ @Syed, if you need to add extra context, please edit that into the question, and not after every answer. More than one line of code doesn't display very well in comments, as you can see `:)`.

Comment: then the above script should work. the problem is your $balance variable is not being defined somewhere in your script. double check how everything stores into that variable and try to see if there's any typos.

OR post how it all flows into the $balance variable and I'll try to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

```
include ("account.php"); 
if (isset ($ _POST ['a'])) {
 $pass = $ _POST ['contraseña1']; 
 $key = 'ccc5545fd';
 $password = 'de4256f'; 
 $nexmo_balance = new NexmoAccount ($ key, $ secreta); 
 $Saldo = $ nexmo_balance-> Balance ();
}
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction(<?php echo $Saldo; ?>)" value="Check Balance" />
<script>
function myFunction(balance)
{
    alert("Your Total Balance is : " + balance + " Euro  ");
}

</script>
```

Comment: This is showin undefined Euros....

here is my php script.

    include ( "account.php" );
    if(isset($_POST['to'])){
    $pass = $_POST['password1'];
    $key = 'ccc5545fd';
    $password = 'de4256f';
    $nexmo_balance = new NexmoAccount($key, $secret);
    $balance = $nexmo_balance->balance();